# C++ Using System::String::Split

Tags: string, c++-cli

I am trying to split a System::String at ":" using System::String::Split in my C++ code. The string to be split is called "responseString". It is a System::String. I have:

```
 char id[] = { ':' };
 return responseString->Split(id);
```

However, it errors at the "->" saying that no instance of the overloaded function matches the argument list. I checked the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and see no information on doing this in C++.

I also tried the following, with the same results:

```
 System::Char id[] = { ':' };
 return responseString->Split(id);
```

In the documentation it shows the following example, but I do not know what to do with that:

```
array<String^>^ Split(
... array<wchar_t>^ separator
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Galik I just added in that responseString is a System::String.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Just tried that, same error sadly.

Comment: You need to use a managed array: `array<Char>^ id = { ':' };`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Symbol delimiter  can be either of type wchar_t, either  String ^, as well as their array.
Here's a quick example:

```
String ^str="String:need:split;this";
array<wchar_t> ^id = { ':' ,';'};
array<String^> ^StringArray =str->Split(':');
array<String^> ^StringArray2 =str->Split(id);
for each(String^ temp in StringArray)
    Console::WriteLine(temp);
Console::WriteLine();
for each(String^ temp in StringArray2)
    Console::WriteLine(temp);
```