# How to split a String at newlines?

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2019

```
String^ exportedFunctions = textBoxFunctions->Text.Split("\n");
```

I get an **error**:

```
Expression must have class type
```

Why is it everytime I search for a solution to a problem I get answers without the `::` or `->` notation?

Like if I google for `c# get winform value` I get an answer along the lines of:

```
winformElement.Value
```

But it won't work unless I actually type:

```
winformElement->Value
```

My Project is a `CLR` project with the WYSIWYG winform editor.

Comment: `String^` and `textBoxFunctions->Text.Split("\n")` is for C++/CLI, not C#. C++/CLI is not C# - they're completely different programming languages. "CLR" is not a programming language.

Comment: Also, in general, splitting on `\n` will leave-behind straggling `\r` characters (because Windows uses `\r\n` to represent a line-break, not a singular `\n` like on macOS and *nix). You'll need to `.Trim` each line (in C# Linq this would be `List<String> lines = textBox.Text.Split( "\n" ).Select( line => line.Trim() ).ToList();`

Comment: My mistake.  I looked back and my project template was `CLR Empty Project (.NET` followed by either `CORE)` or `Framework)`.  I see the language is `C++`.

Comment: Use [Environment::NewLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=netcore-3.1) instead of `\n`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063239/c-using-systemstringsplit).

```cpp
array<String^>^ mySplitString = myString->Split('\n');
```